# Update database manually in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: html, css, .net, visual-studio-2019

I am receiving this error after updating my database through the view data UI.

> The data in this cell has been changed. The change has not been committed to the database. The original value was NULL. Press ESC to revert this cell to it's original value.

Update-database is not working.

How am I able to update the database manually to solve this issue?

Comment: Add your code here for further understanding.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ @dqlgnoleht has given good advice. You have much more chance of getting an answer if SO contributors can see the code you've tried, and the question becomes more useful for future visitors as well. Please take a moment to read how to add a Minimal Reproducible Example into your post >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi. Please also do appropriate tagging. you have a DB problem. But you didn''t tell us how you access the db and what's your db engine and what programming language you're using. (you tagged html, css instead)